# Como passar o id para a função de exclusão

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma to-do list, consigo criar os campos com as tarefas, e os elementos com javascript, porém quando clico no botão de fechar, o único campo que desaparece é o último. Eu coloco os elementos criados em um array em forma de objeto e atribuo um valor a cada array criado, mas não consigo passar esse valor pra função de exclusão de forma que o botão exclua todo o campo. O que posso fazer?

```js
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var index = 0;
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createElement("button");
  var xis = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");

  span.appendChild(txt);
  txt.appendChild(xis);
  txt.className = "close";
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(txt);

}


var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function newElement() {

  var li = document.createElement("input");
  var ul = document.createElement("input");
  var done = document.createElement("input");
  done.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  var inputText = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var inputDate = document.getElementById("time").value;

  done.className = "checkIn";
  li.value = inputText;
  li.className = "valor";
  ul.value = inputDate;
  ul.className = "data";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createElement("button");
  var xis = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");

  span.appendChild(txt);
  txt.appendChild(xis);
  txt.className = "close";

  if (inputText === '') {
    alert("Você precisa digitar algo primeiro!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("recent").appendChild(done).style.width = "20px";
    document.getElementById("recent").appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("recent").appendChild(ul).style.width = "90px";
    document.getElementById("recent").appendChild(span);

  }

  array.push({
    inputtexto: li,
    inputdata: ul,
    close: txt
  })
  index++;

  for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentNode;
      div.style.display = "none";
      done.style.display = "none";
      li.style.display = "none";
      ul.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="add-task">Título:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" name="titulo">
    <label for="date">Prazo:</label>
    <input type="date" id="time" name="data" /><br><br>
    <span onclick="newElement();" class="addBtn" id="newtask" style="cursor:pointer">Add</span>
  </form>
  <div id="recent" class="recent">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tem vários problemas no código, sendo um dos mais diretos este `close.lenght` em que `length` tá mal escrito. A ideia de criar os nós todos à mão é para aprender? Porque essa criação de html fica muito mais simples criando uma string com o novo html e alterando diretamente com `innerHTML`. O `for (var i...) { close[i] =function(){..` tem também um problema de closures

Comment: lenght corrigido. Sim, ainda estou aprendendo por isso prefiro fazer tudo à mão e com javascript puro.Agradeço se você puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- O problema de maior, assim como o @DvD já tinha dito é mesmo o fato de faltar um elemento html para englobar cada nova linha que é inserida, pois os campos são inseridos de forma seguida, acabando por não ter nenhum elemento pai que os agrupe. Isso dificulta a ação de esconder.
- O código que tem inicialmente antes da função `newElement` não é necessário pois tenta adicionar elementos com base na quantidade de `<li>` do documento, mas não ha nenhum.
- Cada vez que adiciona um novo elemento ao html não precisa de um `for` para atribuir todas as funções de `click` dos `closes`, mas sim apenas a do elemento que foi adicionado.
- Tem um problema de [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) em:

  ```
   for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
       close[i].onclick = function() {
  ```

  Porque o `i` vai acabar por não ter escopo do `for` e todos os closes irão referir o ultimo `i`. Considere o seguinte exemplo verificável do problema:

  ```js
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".s");

  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i){
    spans[i].onclick = function(){
      console.log("click no span numero " + i);
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  Clique nos números que se seguem:
  <span class="s">1</span>
  <span class="s">2</span>
  <span class="s">3</span>
  <span class="s">4</span>
  <span class="s">5</span>
  ```

Aqui vê claramente que o `i` não tem escopo do `for` e acaba sendo o mesmo para todos os elementos. Para além disso fica no valor em que saiu do `for` que é `5` e so temos `spans` de `0` a `4`.

Neste momento uma das formas mais simples de resolver este problema é declarando o `i` com `let` que garante o escopo do `for` e faz com que o *closure* funcione como esperado:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".s");

for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i){
  spans[i].onclick = function(){
    console.log("click no span numero " + i);
  }
}
```

```html
Clique nos números que se seguem:
<span class="s">1</span>
<span class="s">2</span>
<span class="s">3</span>
<span class="s">4</span>
<span class="s">5</span>
```

Acertando esses pormenores o seu código ficaria assim:

```js
var index = 0;
var array = [];

//obter o elemento do html apenas uma vez
const recent = document.getElementById("recent"); 

function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("input");
  var ul = document.createElement("input");
  var done = document.createElement("input");
  done.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  var inputText = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var inputDate = document.getElementById("time").value;

  done.className = "checkIn";
  li.value = inputText;
  li.className = "valor";
  ul.value = inputDate;
  ul.className = "data";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createElement("button");
  var xis = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");

  span.appendChild(txt);
  txt.appendChild(xis);
  txt.className = "close";

  if (inputText === '') {
    alert("Você precisa digitar algo primeiro!");
  } else {
    //todos os elementos são adicionados ao novo div que os agrupa
    newdiv.appendChild(done).style.width = "20px";
    newdiv.appendChild(li);
    newdiv.appendChild(ul).style.width = "90px";
    newdiv.appendChild(span);
    recent.appendChild(newdiv); //novo div adicionado ao recent
  }

  array.push({
    inputtexto: li,
    inputdata: ul,
    close: txt
  });
  index++;
  
  //clique do close apenas definido para o elemento adicionado
  txt.onclick = function() {
      this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="add-task">Título:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" name="titulo">
    <label for="date">Prazo:</label>
    <input type="date" id="time" name="data" /><br><br>
    <span onclick="newElement();" class="addBtn" id="newtask" style="cursor:pointer">Add</span>
  </form>
  <div id="recent" class="recent">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

No entanto, e assim como tinha já dito em comentários, a construção de novo html fica muito mais simplificada com strings. Estas strings guardam toda a estrutura html a adicionar já com atributos e classes, e é aplicada diretamente no `innerHTML`.

Exemplo com `strings` e `innerHTML`:

```js
const inputText = document.getElementById("myInput");
const inputDate = document.getElementById("time");
const recent = document.getElementById("recent");

function newElement() {
  if (inputText.value === '') {
    alert("Você precisa digitar algo primeiro!");
    return;
  }
  
  let newHtml = `<div class="linha">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="checkIn" style="width:20px;">
                   <input type="text" value="${inputText.value}">
                   <input type="text" value="${inputDate.value}" style="width:90px;">               
                   <span><button class="close">\u00D7</button></span>
                 </div>`;
   recent.innerHTML += newHtml;
   
   for (let l of document.querySelectorAll(".linha .close")){
      l.onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="add-task">Título:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" name="titulo">
    <label for="date">Prazo:</label>
    <input type="date" id="time" name="data" /><br><br>
    <span onclick="newElement();" class="addBtn" id="newtask" style="cursor:pointer">Add</span>
  </form>
  <div id="recent" class="recent">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Neste ultimo caso como o `innerHTML` é aplicado diretamente no `<div id="recente">` torna-se necessário voltar a aplicar os eventos de `close` a todas as linhas.

Comment: Obrigada por responder e pela matéria do link, pois, foi muito esclarecedora.

Answer (score 0):

O correto é você criar um *container* (ou *wrapper*) (uma `div` ou um `span`, por exemplo) para cada item adicionado. Da forma que está fazendo, os elementos ficam sem uma referência própria. Veja abaixo a estrutura de como ficam os item adicionados:

```
<div id="recent" class="recent">
  checkbox
  input texto
  input datepicker
  <span>
    botao X
  </span>

  checkbox
  input texto
  input datepicker
  <span>
    botao X
  </span>
</div>
```

Veja que os itens, que deveriam pertencer a um mesmo grupo, possuem como referência comum apenas a div-pai `id="recent"`, tornando o trabalho complicado, pois fico sem poder selecionar os elementos-filhos que eu quero.

Como mencionado, crie uma `div` para agrupar os elementos, ficando assim:

```
<div id="recent" class="recent">
  <div class="itens">
    checkbox
    input texto
    input datepicker
    <span>
      botao X
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="itens">
    checkbox
    input texto
    input datepicker
    <span>
      botao X
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiz as alterações comentadas na função abaixo:

```
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("input");
  var ul = document.createElement("input");
  var done = document.createElement("input");
  var lista = document.createElement("div"); // criar uma div para agrupar os itens
  lista.setAttribute("class", "itens"); // atribuí uma classe à div
  done.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  var inputText = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var inputDate = document.getElementById("time").value;

  done.className = "checkIn";
  li.value = inputText;
  li.className = "valor";
  ul.value = inputDate;
  ul.className = "data";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createElement("button");
  var xis = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");

  span.appendChild(txt);
  txt.appendChild(xis);
  txt.className = "close";

  if (inputText === '') {
    alert("Você precisa digitar algo primeiro!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("recent").appendChild(lista); // adiciono a div à div-pai
    ultimo_item = document.getElementsByClassName("itens").length-1; // conto quantas divs possui e subtraio por 1 para pegar o index, que começa com 0
    document.getElementsByClassName("itens")[ultimo_item].appendChild(done).style.width = "20px"; // daqui pra baixo eu adiciono os elementos dentro da div
    document.getElementsByClassName("itens")[ultimo_item].appendChild(li);
    document.getElementsByClassName("itens")[ultimo_item].appendChild(ul).style.width = "90px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("itens")[ultimo_item].appendChild(span);

  }

  array.push({
    inputtexto: li,
    inputdata: ul,
    close: txt
  })
  index++;

  for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentNode.parentNode; // seleciono o avô do span que oculta o item
      div.style.display = "none"; // oculto a div
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta

Comment: @JessicaKeilla De nada! Obg!